# Analyzing a stream of timestamped accelerometer data to find the start and end of certain motion patterns

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, machine-learning-model

I'm new to machine learning, so sorry in advance if this is not a useful question.

But I'm hoping to get a few clues to start additional research.

As part of my project, I've attached an 6-axis sensor (accelerometer/gyroscope) to the end of a golf club. That sensor is streaming data to my computer, at preset intervals (e.g., every 10ms). So I'm getting 6 series of data.

The sensor stream will stream continuously, before, during, and after a "golf swing", through multiple swings (e.g., over the span of 30 minutes).

My goal is to use machine learning to be able to analyze that stream, and identify when each swing starts and ends.

I.e., while the sensor is moving randomly and unpredictably in between swings, I suspect that the particular nature of a golf swing will create an identifiable pattern that an algorithm may be able to discern.

So, for example - if you provided the algorithm with 30 minutes of streaming data, during which time the golf club was swung 30 times, the algorithm would be able to identify when each swung started and finished, and be able to analyze each one.

Does this sound feasible?

Can anyone point me in the direction of particular topics that would be useful in a project like this?

Thanks in advance.